# Is there a way to temporarily store a query result in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've been trying to improve the complexity of this code. I searched through a lot of SO questions, but I think that's not what I wanted. I want to get 10 longest and shortest life expectancy countries - that's what the UNION is for. And as you can see there are two identical subqueries.

```
(SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT name, life_expectancy 
    FROM country_info
    WHERE life_expectancy!="null") AS life_expectancy_table
ORDER BY life_expectancy DESC
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT name, life_expectancy 
    FROM country_info
    WHERE life_expectancy!="null") AS life_expectancy_table
ORDER BY life_expectancy
LIMIT 10)
```

I suspect that the subquery is being run 2 times and that is the thing I want to avoid. Moreover, even if the query is not being run 2 times, I would like to use an alias to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a fine method, but doesn't require so many subqueries:

```
(SELECT name, life_expectancy 
 FROM country_info
 WHERE life_expectancy <> 'null' 
 ORDER BY life_expectancy DESC
 LIMIT 10
) UNION  -- intentional to remove duplicates
(SELECT name, life_expectancy 
 FROM country_info
 WHERE life_expectancy <> 'null'
 ORDER BY life_expectancy
 LIMIT 10
);
```

It seems very strange that `life_expectancy` would be stored as a string.  You may intend `life_expectancy IS NOT NULL`.

You can also do this with window functions:

```
 SELECT name, life_expectancy 
 FROM (SELECT ci.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY life_expectancy DESC) as seqnum_desc,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY life_expectancy ASC) as seqnum_asc
       FROM country_info ci
       WHERE life_expectancy <> 'null'
      ) t
 WHERE seqnum_desc <= 10 OR seqnum_asc <= 10;
```

Comment: So my solution at first was almost exactly like yours, but then I thought about the complexity - here you run almost the same query 2 times, using the subquery I wanted to optimize the solution.
I'm using life_expectancy here as string, because it's from JSON.
Still my question is can you store a result of one query in let's say a variable?
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Damian . . . You cannot store the results of a query (sensibly) in a variable.  You can store the results in a temporary table, but I don't recommend that.  The two queries are quite different because the `ORDER BY` clauses are different.